# How to draw DPDA for language $L = \{a^ncb^{2n} | n \geq1\}$over the alphabet $\Sigma =\{a,b,c\} ?$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

An exercise problem $:$

Give a deterministic PDA for the language $L = \{a^ncb^{2n} | n \geq1\}$over the alphabet $\Sigma =\{a,b,c\}$.Specify the acceptance state.

---

My attempt $:$

Grammar of given language is :

G: S → aSbb | c

We can recognize string of $L$ :

1. Push all a's in the stack ,
2. Excape 'c',
3. Pop single a's from stack for every two b's of string,
4. If the final stack is empty/final state then string in the given language else not .

Since , we are recognizing string of the language ,so $L$ is DCFL.

I find the PDA([see-page-no.-26](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps140/spring03/lects/sectnpdaS.pdf)) for the $L = \{a^nb^{2n} | n \geq1\}$over the alphabet $\Sigma =\{a,b\}$.

---

> Can you please give explanation to draw DPDA for language $L =
>  \{a^ncb^{2n} | n \geq1\}$over the alphabet $\Sigma =\{a,b,c\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one:**
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$

> [image]